# contar registros de una tabla

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

buenas  necesito mostrar un conteo   lo estoy trabajando con un listado y  lambda   de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach (var item in Denuncias)
                            {
                                var DenunciaPersona = dbDP.TraerTodo().Where(x => x.NODENUNCIA == item.NODENUNCIA);
                                var hecho = dbhe.TraerHechos((long)item.AÑO, (long)item.NODENUNCIA).Where(x => x.NODENUNCIA == item.NODENUNCIA).FirstOrDefault();
                                var citaciones = dbci.TraerCitaciones((long)item.AÑO, (long)item.NODENUNCIA);
                                var clasedenuncia = dbcla.TraerTodo().Where(x => x.CLASE_DENUNCIA == item.CLASE_DENUNCIA);
                                DateTime? ultimaCitacion = null;
                                  <tr>                              
                                  <td nowrap>                                            
                                        @foreach (var d in DenunciaPersona)
                                        {
                                            int prueba = DenunciaPersona.Count(den => den.TIPO_PERSONA == 1);
                                            if (d.TIPO_PERSONA == 1)
                                            {

                                                    <span> cantidad de victimas:@prueba</span>

                                            }
                                        }
                                        <br />
                                        Clase Denuncia: @denuncia
                                    </td>

                                   </tr>
```

si me lo esta contando pero  me lo muestra de la siguinte manera:    CANTIDAD DE VICTIMAS: 2 CANTIDAD DE VICTIMAS: 2   Y lo deseo solo  asi: CANTIDAD DE VICTIMAS 2

Comment: Elimina el `@foreach (var d in DenunciaPersona)`. No lo estás usando de todas maneras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dice sstan en su [comentario](http://Como%20bien%20dice%20sstan%20en%20su%20comentario,), el `@foreach (var d in DenunciaPersona)` no lo estás usando y no es requerido, es por eso que te muestra la información duplicada, ya que por cada `DenunciaPersona` estás imprimiendo la información en pantalla. Simplemente quita ese segmento de código y funcionará de acuerdo a lo que necesitas.

La validación `if (d.TIPO_PERSONA == 1)` tampoco es necesaria ya que la estás incluyendo en el `Count(den => den.TIPO_PERSONA == 1);` que estás realizando. El código quedaría algo así:

```
@foreach (var item in Denuncias)
{
    var DenunciaPersona = dbDP.TraerTodo().Where(x => x.NODENUNCIA == item.NODENUNCIA);
    var hecho = dbhe.TraerHechos((long)item.AÑO, (long)item.NODENUNCIA).Where(x => x.NODENUNCIA == item.NODENUNCIA).FirstOrDefault();
    var citaciones = dbci.TraerCitaciones((long)item.AÑO, (long)item.NODENUNCIA);
    var clasedenuncia = dbcla.TraerTodo().Where(x => x.CLASE_DENUNCIA == item.CLASE_DENUNCIA);
    DateTime? ultimaCitacion = null;
    <tr>                              
        <td nowrap>
            int prueba = DenunciaPersona.Count(den => den.TIPO_PERSONA == 1);
            <span> cantidad de victimas:@prueba</span>
            <br />
            Clase Denuncia: @denuncia // --> Esto te va a marcar un error o simplemente verás en el html tal cual está: Clase Denuncia: @denuncia
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Como observación adicional, recomendaría que no accedas al modelo de datos directamente desde un View, no es la mejor práctica y se convierte en un código difícil de dar mantenimiento a futuro. Lo ideal es que esa información la obtengas desde un Controller y envíes la información necesaria al View.